# setAlert function not working when using it in service component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I created a class named alert, and I use it to display alerts whenever new post is created or deleted or changed.
but there is one issue, when I put the setAlert inside a DELETE/POST/PUT function, if the latter is located inside a service component, it gives me an error saying: [ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is4yH.png)

but when I move the function into its component.ts file, it works properly without any issues. So why is that happening and what can I do to make it work in a service?

Here is my Alert.ts:

```
export class alert{
    "status" : boolean;
    "text": string;
    constructor(){
        this.status=false;
        this.text="";
    }
    public setAlert(text){
        this.status = true;
        this.text = text;
    }
    public close(){
        this.status = false;
    }
}
```

Here is my html file:

```
<div class="forms container">
  <form #postForm="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input [(ngModel)]="formService.form.title"
          name="title"  
          id="title" 
          type="text" 
          class="form-control"
          >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="body">Body</label>
        <textarea [(ngModel)]="formService.form.body" 
        name= "body" 
        id="body" 
        cols="30" 
        rows="10" 
        class="form-control"
        ></textarea>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-success" (click) = "formService.editForm()">Save</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right" (click) = "formService.deleteForm()">Delete</button>

      <div class="container mt-4">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div *ngIf = "alert.status"  class="alert alert-success 
            alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"
              (click) = "alert.close()">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
              {{alert.text}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

Here is component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormService } from './forms.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { alert } from './alert';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-forms',
  templateUrl: './forms.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forms.component.css']
})


export class FormsComponent implements OnInit {

  alert: alert;
  id: any;
  posts: any;

  constructor(public formService: FormService ,private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router, private http: HttpClient) { }



  ngOnInit() {
    this.id=this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.alert = new alert();

    this.posts = this.formService.getForms(this.id).subscribe(
      (forms: any) => {
        this.formService.form = forms[0];
      }
    );
  }

}
```

And here is service.ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { form } from './form-interface';
import { alert } from './alert';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
}) 

export class FormService {

  formsUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
  form: form = {
      id: 0,
      userId: 0,
      title: '',
      body: ''
  };
  alert: alert;


    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.alert = new alert();
    }

    getForms(id) {
            return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
            + "?id=" + id)
    }

    editForm() {
        fetch(this.formsUrl + "/" + this.form.id, {
          method: 'PUT',
          body: JSON.stringify(this.form),
          headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
          }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        this.alert.setAlert("Post has been successfully saved !");
    }

    deleteForm() {
        this.http.delete(this.formsUrl + "/" + this.form.id)
        .subscribe(
          data  => {
            console.log("DELETE Request is successful ", data);
            this.alert.setAlert("Post has been successfully deleted !");

          },
          error  => {
            console.log("Error", error);
          }
        );
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services don't have `ngOnInit` life cycle, change your code from `ngOnInit` to `constructor`.

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
  this.alert = new alert();
}
```

Only components and directives have life cycle hooks:

> A Component has a lifecycle managed by Angular itself. Angular creates it, >renders it, creates and renders its children, checks it when its data-bound >properties change and destroy it before removing it from the DOM.
>
> Directive and component instances have a lifecycle as Angular creates, updates, >and destroys them.